# Crash / Memory Warning when taking a picture - iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory, crash, camera

I am getting a memory warning and the app is crashing during the time when a photo is taken with the iPhone. Not sure how to address this because the code that opens the camera works - and the code after a picture is captured works, but the error is somewhere in the camera taking a picture section of the app...

I'm starting the camera like this:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) 
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
else 
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
} else if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
}

imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I am getting "Received memory warning." right before Recorder_SourceStarted and AVCaptureDeviceDidStartRunningNotification.

I then get Recorder_DidStartPreviewing, Recorder_FlashStateChanged, Recorder_DidStartFocusOperation, Recorder_DidCompleteFocusOperation, Recorder_FlashStateChanged, Recorder_WillCapturePhoto, Recorder_DidCapturePhoto, and Recorder_PhotoStillImageSampleBufferReady before the app crashes.

Recorder_PhotoStillImageSampleBufferReady is the last notification I am getting before the app crashes. It doesn't make it to _UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem at which point the app starts running code I wrote again.

Sometimes it doesn't crash...  I get the memory warning and the app continues working as it should, but the potential is there for a crash because of this memory warning and I'm getting crashes in testing so I'd like to figure out what is causing this and fix it.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything in your `- (void)didreceivememorywarning` function?

Comment: No... is there anything I can put there that would help figure this out?

Comment: In terms of diagnosing why you are running out of memory, you should probably use the 'Leaks' tool in Instruments.  This will show any memory leaks you may have.  the `-(void)didreceivememorywarning` is called when you receive a "low memory" warning, so you can release and clean any unnecessary variables.

Comment: An example, in an app I was writing, I was releasing the backgroundImage in my `didreceivememorywarning` function, and in my `viewwillappear` I was trying to manipulate that background image.  So as soon as the picture finished taking and tried to return to the main view, my app crashed because that variable had been released.  but if you haven't implemented the `didreceivememorywarning` then that won't apply.

Comment: I don't understand Instruments all too well, but just ran it and used the app until the crash of snapping a photo - Allocations were moving along but no Leaks showed in Instruments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was alloc'ing tableViews in the app (not dealloc'ing because it's using ARC) and apparently after the calls to alloc tableViews had been made, trying to capture a picture would cause a memory crash. I changed it to set the .hidden property on the tableviews on and off when users needed to see the table instead of alloc'ing each time a tableview was requested and now the app never crashes when a picture is taken. Sometimes there is still a memory warning, but never a crash, and often no memory warning at all when I take a picture.